# play framework Logging ebean SQL statments

Tags: playframework, ebean, playframework-2.2

I'm using play 2.2.0 How cam I log ebean sql I tried

```
db.default.logStatements=true
logger.com.jolbox=DEBUG
```

In config file but no luck.
should I add any code to my models or create extra config files?
what Is the configuration working for this version?

Comment: This config works for me. Try to "play clean compile" the project.

Comment: on which version you are using?

Comment: same as yours - 2.2.0

Comment: Do you have application-logger.xml set up?

Comment: Are you doing `play run` or `play start`?

Comment: Application Logger?? No
I'm using play run

Comment: Check that you run play in dev mode, in prod mode you are not able to log sql statements

Comment: Check if you had line like this: 
logger.application=DEBUG

Also tell, please, what database are you using: mysql, postgersql, etc.

Comment: It Is in my config already
I'm using mysql

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hi you need to add logger.xml to your `/conf/logger.xml`.

```
<configuration>
    <timestamp key="bySecond" datePattern="yyyy_MM_dd_HH_mm"/>
    <appender name="STDOUT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
        <encoder>
            <pattern>%-5level - %msg%n</pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>

    <appender name="FILE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.FileAppender">
        <file>${application.home}/logs/application-${bySecond}.txt</file>
        <encoder>
            <pattern>%date - [%level] - from %logger in %thread %n%message%n%xException%n</pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>

    <logger name="com.jolbox.bonecp" level="DEBUG">
        <appender-ref ref="FILE" />
    </logger>
    <logger name="com.jolbox.bonecp" level="DEBUG">
        <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
    </logger>

    <logger name="play" level="DEBUG">
        <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
        <appender-ref ref="FILE" />
    </logger>

    <logger name="application" level="DEBUG">
        <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
        <appender-ref ref="FILE" />

    </logger>

</configuration>
```

This: `com.jolbox.bonecp` will be adding all sql to console and will write to file `application-currentdate.log`.