# Database first ORM for Play Framework (Java) with auto DB model generating

Tags: java, orm, playframework, playframework-2.0, database-first

Several years I develop at work in C#, MVC, Entity Framework, database first. Now I want to try Java and choose Play Framework and IDEA as IDE. 
Now I search such ORM system as:

- easy integrating in Play Framework;
- have class generation from database (reverse engineering) as main tool;
- have easy language like LINQ in C# (ex: from x in context.MY_TABLE select x)

Answer (score 2):

I strongly advice using [jOOQ](https://jooq.org/):

- Support to generate model classes from console by only one command: `java -classpath jooq-3.1.0.jar;jooq-meta-3.1.0.jar;jooq-codegen-3.1.0.jar;postgresql-9.2-1003.jdbc4.jar;. org.jooq.util.GenerationTool /jooq_config.xml`
- Full control of your SQL queries.
- Easy SQL debugging. Very easy: [see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20375926/play-framework-logging-ebean-sql-statments/20401184#20401184).
- Flexible and powerfull API. [Full documentation](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual-single-page/).
- Typefase.
- Ideal choose for `SQL` indepth programming.
- Supports Java and Scala.
- Out-of-box support for advanced SQL types without problems.
- Build-in exporting to xml, html, excel
- Build-in support to batch inserting.
- Good support.
- Opensource
- Many database engines supported.

## Personal feelings

I always loved `SQL` and I really had chance to work with many `ORM` with many technologies (`.NET: NHibernate, Entity Framework, Linq. Java: Hibernate, JPA. Scala: Anorm SQL`) and there were no good solution for me. I used `model first` and `database first`. Everytime I used raw SQL and store procedures in most critical points of applications. ORM generate a lot of rubbish which is very difficult to profile and optimize.

When I found jOOQ I was very skeptical. After about 6-8 months working with it I knew that was it. This tool allow you to write every query similar to raw SQL and it's very productive tool. Next thing is that this tool is really fast growing.

Answer (score 1):

Play has build-in ORM - it's Ebean, all you need to use it just uncomment several lines in application.conf (and optionally choose database engine other then build-in H2 ie. MySQL like described in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10007515/1066240))

Next create `models` package in `app` folder and start to add your models.

More details in [official docs](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.2.x/JavaEbean).

Unfortunately it doesn't support reverse engineering...

Comment: Reverse engineered models are not possible in Ebean, unfortunately.

Comment: Yeah actually forgot to add this sorry... fortunately DDL generation works like a charm in the second direction.

Comment: Anyway, thanks! Maybe, need to change my mind and code-first will be good (especially for little projects), but then I can't say to boss that open source is better than MS products, because open source doesn't have tools for easy programming, to concentrate programmers on logic layer, and let data layer to special people - db archinteriors.

Comment: First you need to... _ride the beast_ :) In Play with Ebean the development can be easy divided to modelling and main development phase, the main difference is that you create DLL from Java models declarations not in the reverse order. It's important at beginning to realise how changes in model classes affects the DDL generator. De facto it's my favourite phase of each project ;) keep thumbs!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not aware if IDEA supports DB -> JPA entities reverse-engineering, but Eclipse Dali does this fine - I have used this approach on several projects and were happy with it.

http://www.eclipse.org/webtools/dali/

Play2 works ok with full JPA if wished. Ebean uses only JPA annotations. I like EBean since even if I'm not completely convinced about JPA's criteria API (I have went it thru on JPA 2.0, so don't know how much easier it has come on JPA 2.1) & usefulness of EntityMananager (all hassle with connected / disconnedted entities) I'm big fan of JPA annotations.

For anyone interested in JPA I recommend this book

[http://www.amazon.com/Pro-JPA-2-Mike-Keith/dp/1430249269/](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1430249269)

BTW: JPA's named queries / JPQL might be ok for sql like simple query needs. Ebean doesn't support JPQL, so if one wants to use it then full JPA implementation like Hibernate or EclipseLink is needed.

Answer (score 0):

Jooq doesn't support nested objects. The idea is good, but not very useful.

Comment: The jOOQ approach assumes that you don't really want that, at least not in a strictly OO way. Instead, you want to get a stream of tuples from the database, and possibly, transform that stream of tuples in a FP way. An example can be seen in this post about [A functional programming approach to dynamic SQL with jOOQ](https://blog.jooq.org/2017/01/16/a-functional-programming-approach-to-dynamic-sql-with-jooq/)