# Play Framework 2.0 Ebean ArrayList Null

Tags: java, arraylist, playframework, playframework-2.0, ebean

In the Java version of Play Framework 2.0, Im trying to save an ArrayList of a class of mine called `Post` in another class of mine `ForumThread`. Now, in the constructor for `ForumThread`, I make a new `Post` and add it to an ArrayList of posts, and then save my database. However, after I save any instances of `ForumThread`, the ArrayList of `Post`s becomes null. This is causing an error when I render my page, and my question here is twofold.

1) How do I make my `ForumThread`'s ArrayList of Posts not become null as soon as it is saved?

2) Why does it become null as soon as it is saved.

All relevant code is below, and as a note, I have tried using @ManyToOne and @OneToMany annotations with no success, this is the code before attempting that.

ForumThread.java

```
package models;

import java.util.*;
import controllers.*;
import play.db.ebean.*;
import play.data.validation.Constraints.*;

import javax.persistence.*;

@Entity
@Table(name="threads")
public class ForumThread extends Model{

    @Id
    public long id;

    @Column
    @Required
    public String title;

    @Column
    public User creator;

    @Column
    public List<Post> posts  = new ArrayList<Post>();

    public String initialMessage;

    public static play.db.ebean.Model.Finder<Long, ForumThread> find = new Finder<Long, ForumThread>(Long.class, ForumThread.class);

    public ForumThread(User creator, String title, String initialMessage) {
        this.creator = creator;
        this.title = title;
        Post initialPost = new Post(creator, initialMessage, title);
        this.posts.add(initialPost);
    }

    public static void create(ForumThread thread){
        thread.save();
    }

    public static List<ForumThread> all(){
        return find.all();
    }
}
```

Post.java

```
package models;

import java.util.*;

public class Post{
    public User poster;
    public String message;
    public String title;

    public Post(User poster, String message, String title){
        this.poster = poster;
        this.message = message;
        this.title = title;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Turn on ebean database logging.  See this article:  [play framework Logging ebean SQL statments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20375926/play-framework-logging-ebean-sql-statments)

Then you can see what ebean is doing.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your `Posts` class is just a POJO. Should be extending `Model` and should also have an `@Entity`, `@Table`, etc annotations.

Answer (score 0):

To be sure that everything gets inferred correctly, implement a bidirectional relationship between ForumThread and Post, indicating the attribute that maps the posts to a thread and using a cascading save:

```
@Entity
public class ForumThread extends Model{
    ...
    @OneToMany(mappedBy="thread",cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    public List<Post> posts;
    ...
}


@Entity
public class Post extends Model{
    ...
    @ManyToOne
    public ForumThread thread;
    ...
}
```

see the ebean userguide http://www.avaje.org/doc/ebean-userguide.pdf